# Grep files having function with particular word in unix

Tags: php, bash, unix

I need to grep all the files recursively in a directory which have a function having "include" or "include_once" statement called within it.

Tried below options but no luck:

`grep -ir "function.*\n*.*include" *`

`grep -ir "function.*[[space]]*.*include" *`

*Please note that I need files having any function definition with include statement

Sample file which should be found in grep say: "testgrep.php":

`<?php
function getData()
{
        $myobj = new MAIN_TABLE();
        include("connections_db.php");
        getConnection();// Defined in connections_db.php
        $result= $myobj->getData();
}`
?>

Thus this file have a function getData() which have include called in it.

Sample file which should not be found in grep say: "testnegativegrep.php":

`<?php
include("connections_db.php");
function getData()
{
        $myobj = new MAIN_TABLE();
        getConnection();// Defined in connections_db.php
        $result= $myobj->getData();
}`
?>

Thus this file have a function getData() but dont have include called in it.

Please help!!

Comment: You're looking for the name of the functions that contain directives include and include_once?

Comment: I just need file names having functions that contain include directives

Comment: provide sample data to work with.

Comment: if you use code formatting tools (I assume php has them), then just grep for includes on lines that start with a tab.

Answer (score 2):

with gnu grep:

```
find /path/to/directory -iname "*.php" | xargs egrep 'include|include_once'
```

Comment: I need the case in which include is called in a function. Above solution provide all the files with include or include_once called in them

Comment: @RuhiSingh, Provide sample input and output. Nobody will work on an imaginary data.